# Implement a simple MPEG-TS muxer using ffmpeg-lib

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavformat, transport-stream, muxer

I have an application that records raw **audio** data in LPCM stored in a buffer. I would like to encapsulate the data in a transport stream and send that transport stream through UDP to a stream segmenter (according to HTTP Live Streaming specifications) on another host.

FFmpeg provides a command-line utility to do so but with a file as input 
`ffmpeg -re -i output.aac -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:5555`.

My first thought was to use FFmpeg API, especially the **libavformat** library. Does libavformat provide a muxer that I could use to encapsulate my audio in LPCM into a transport stream or do I have to implement it from scratch?

I have found this source code https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/mpegts.c but I am not sure if it actually does what I'm looking for.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: `libavformat/mpegtsenc.c` is the TS muxer but it does not mux LPCM. Patch welcome.

Comment: Does it have any kind of documentation or do I have to dive into the code?

Comment: Individual muxers aren't documented per se. Basic flow is the same: you init, write header (if applicable), write packets, write trailer, deinit. See the relevant functions at the bottom of the file.

Comment: Do you have to have LPCM while it is transferred across the network? Being an uncompressed format it is likely why you can't find what you need as not efficient for network transport. You could encode and transport and the decode back to LPCM would be a fairly straight forward process. If you really just want to push the LPCM across the network just send it on a socket and no need for ffmpeg

Comment: @Andrew No I don't need to transfer in LPCM. My audio is natively produce in LPCM but I can easily encode it in a more suitable format such as AAC. However, I do need to transfer it in a MPEG Transport Stream because it what the server process is expecting.

Comment: @Gyan Transport Streams requires Packetized Elementary Stream. Does ffmeg provide any utility to convert segment an elementary stream?

Answer (score 1):

So based on your comment about not needing it to necessarily be LPCM in the TS you will need to:

1. Decode your audio / read the frames
2. Encode it as a as something suitable for sending in a Transport Stream e.g. mp3 or AAC I believe this is the list of options: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/mpegts.h#L45-L64
3. Package it in a TS suitable for your network conditions e.g. packet sizing etc
4. Send it via UDP

There is a reasonable example of all this here: https://github.com/rvs/ffmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/output-example.c

As mentioned in the prior answer from szatmary you could also just pipe this to ffmpeg which may be simplest

Comment: Thanks. However I can’t use the ffmpeg utility because both the recording and the streaming are embed in my application.

Comment: That code example would be for embedding in your application

Comment: Yes I know, I was just referring to your last sentence :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ts muxer directly via libavformat. However you can also pipe the audio to ffmpeg using -i -

Comment: My goal is to programmatically replicate the ffmeg utility with the libavformat API but thanks anyway